# Donald Knuth's Nontransitive Bingo Cards

Tags: probability, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In **Time Travel and Other Mathematical Bewilderments**, Martin Gardner presents a set of four nontransitive bingo cards designed by Donald Knuth (pp. 61). The rules are that the first player to complete a horizontal row wins. Gardner does not delve into the mathematics but merely mentions that, *probabilistically*, A beats B, B beats C, C beats D, and D beats A.

[image]

I was so baffled that I immediately went on to to verify those results. He was right.

Now, with dice or heads tails sequences, I *can* understand nontransitivity; can someone please give the mathematical explanation of how and why nontransitivity occurs in the above game.

Comment: An observation: Where card $x$ beats card $y$, the numbers on card $x$ that are not on card $y$ are in different rows, but the numbers on card $y$ that are not on card $x$ are in the same row. This gives card $x$ the advantage, although my proof is too long to fit in this comment.

Comment: @SteveKass You and Fermat would have gotten along. :)

Comment: What does it mean for one card to beat another one? Is there a payoff involved? Because clearly there are some situations where B will win before A, etc.

Comment: @IbrahimTencer, the numbers $1$ through $6$ are called out in random permutation.  One card "beats" another if it wins more of the permutations.

Comment: I changed the wording; thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say two players take cards $A$ and $B$ and we roll a 6-sided die to call out the numbers.

If a $1$ or a $3$ is rolled right off the start, then player $B$ cannot win using their top row and must rely on a $5,6$ victory. Player $A$ does not experience this problem if something on player $B$'s card is rolled first.

Comment: Nice observation. That should be the explanation.